# Issues running svelte build using cloudflare and vite: is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: cloudflare, vite, sveltekit

I'm attempting to build a SvelteKit that deploys with Cloudflare using this adaptor https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-cloudflare

However when I run "CF_PAGES=1 vite build" I get the following error "'CF_PAGES' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I suspect I may be missing an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is that you are attempting to run the UNIX command on Microsoft Windows.

Potential solutions

- Translate UNIX command syntax of setting environment variables to Microsoft Windows command syntax. [See here how to set environment variables on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55500857/how-can-i-set-the-environment-variables-in-windows)
- Use a UNIX based workflow on Microsoft Windows, like WSL2 or Docker containers