# Problems with OpenAI Authentification

Tags: python, authentication, api-key, openai-api

I've got some problems with the Authentification to OpenAI in my python code. It seems like, OpenAI doesn't accept my key. I did a new on and tried it with other ones before. I always get the same issues. I just copied and pasted the key, same for the organization. There isn't a typo. There is another problem, but I don't know, why the authentifitaion failed.

Here is my code:
I used it in the same way like the OpenAI Website https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/authentication?lang=python

```
import os
import openai
openai.organization = "org-CXk0SUzbnyzzCLcaSBCFAV64"
openai.api_key = os.getenv("sk-**********************************************9Q")
openai.Model.list()
```

It produces the follwing error:

```
openai.error.AuthenticationError: No API key provided. You can set your API key in code using 'openai.api_key = <API-KEY>', or you can set the environment variable OPENAI_API_KEY=<API-KEY>). If your API key is stored in a file, you can point the openai module at it with 'openai.api_key_path = <PATH>'. You can generate API keys in the OpenAI web interface. See https://onboard.openai.com for details, or email support@openai.com if you have any questions.
```

Did anyone had the some issues before? Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your environment variables are like a dictionary, and the code to retrieve should match the sample code:

```
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
```

However, you have to [set the environment keys first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55500857/2280890).

From your code, it looks like you just want to *hard code* the value, in which case your code should look like:

```
import openai
openai.organization = "org-CXk0SUzbnyzzCLcaSBCFAV64"
openai.api_key = "sk-**********************************************9Q"
openai.Model.list()
```

Comment: @Arenosa, please edit your question with changes and include error messages. Read [ask] for more guidance on how to ask a good question.