# Is process.env a generic environment variable or is it NodeJs specific?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is `process.env` a generic environment variable or is it NodeJs specific?

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env
They have shown how to set it with node command:

```bash
$ node -e 'process.env.foo = "bar"' && echo $foo
```

Is it possible to set it on terminal without node command?

Comment: It's a system thing [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234742/setting-environment-variables-in-linux-using-bash), [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55500857/how-can-i-set-the-environment-variables-in-windows)

Comment: You can also set a temporary variable in bash: `foo=123 node ./filename.js`

Comment: are you asking about "process.env, the Node.js API for accessing your environment variables", or are you asking about the _concept_ of environment variables?

Comment: Why would I write an answer when the Node.js team already [extensively documented this](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/command-line/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs)? The `process.env` instruction is Node-only, and hooks in the universal concept of environment variables, supported by all operating systems.

Answer (score -1):

If you set an environment variable in your shell, that environment variable will be available in your Node scripts. How you set environment variables differs with different shells, but assuming you've set the variable in your shell, it will be available in Node.

In bash, you could set it via `export` or just assigning it directly before the Node command.

```
foo=bar node your_script.js
```

or

```
export foo=bar
node your_script.js
```

If you're on Windows and you're using cmd, you can use `set`:

```
set foo=bar && node your_script.js
```

It is also popular to use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) - it will pick up environment variables from your .env file contained in the root of your project.

**Assigning anything to process.env inside your Node script will not be reflected in your shell.**